# Help me to find a good name for my website

Tags: marketing, domains

I have a web marketing question for you.
I'm looking for a good domain name for my web app.
This site is about writing. Any kind of user generated writings including poetry, aphorisms, short stories, song lyrics etc.
I have some candidates, but I think it can be better. . I want the name to promote very good quality words, not just random facebook-like status updates.
This is my list, but I think you can do better, any help would be very very appreciated.
I promise to add your name in my credit if i pick your answer. Thanks

- Yourwritings
- Youwrite
- Beautifulwords
- thewriter
- writingshare

Comment: What if my suggestion is so great I go ahead and buy the domain before you do? When I'm stuck like this I usually grab a thesaurus and find alternative words for "share", "writing" etc. That usually kick starts the ideas again.

Comment: I think I see 5 new domains I need to register. :) I sometimes use http://nameboy.com/ when I'm stuck on finding a domain name.

Comment: This must be what you call a "domainer's block".

Answer (score 5):

In the spirit of the Chinese proverb *Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime*, here's some tools that may help you now *and* in the future:

- **[domai.nr](http://domai.nr/)** - Give it a few keywords and it will suggest domain names using less common top level domains.  `del.icio.us` is the most famous example of this approach.
- **[bustaname.com](http://www.bustaname.com/)** - Give it a few words and it will show you multiple combinations, suggest synonyms and and variations, and then show you which resulting names are available.
- If you find a name you really like but find it's already taken, you still have some options.  You can use a tool like **[snapnames.com](https://www.snapnames.com/)** or **[domainsbot.com](http://www.domainsbot.com/)** to try to buy the name if it is for sale or bid on it if the current owner allows it to expire.

Comment: I haven't found domai.nr to be that great for anything except for URLs unless your desired word/phrase ends with a TLD. Otherwise, it gives you garbage names like `agdwbste` (a good website) or less-than desirable domain names like: `aw.some.de.si` + `/gns`. But bustaname.com is awesome. I wish I'd known about that when choosing my domain a few weeks ago.

Comment: Oh, also, sometimes domai.nr gives you illegal domains/URLs. For instance, it'll suggest a "domain name" like `ar/t.is.hard` where the "domain" part is just a TLD.

Comment: Be careful with sites like bustaname.com Nothing prevents them from registering frequent keywords.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'prose' encompasses all the aspects of writing.  Perhaps a Domain Name involving that word.

www.composeprose.com is available, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Calliope was the Grek goddess of poetry; Minerva was the Roman goddess of poetry; think calliopeea.com or something similar.
Similar suggestions: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060902060153AAeOhDM
Quipu: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quipu
"bluefingers" - when you write a lot you sometimes get a spot:D
"themeltingpen" - if you write enough you get a melting pen:)

Answer (score 0):

Look to purchase a name. Back in the year 2000 there were so many people thinking up the good names and using keyword generators that all the good names have already been taken. On the plus side this means people already did the hard work already. Making up keywords. So see if they let a good name go for $100. They are not super expensive because most people are not willing to pay more than $100 or so for a domain name.